# How to hide these 'deprecated' type messages when implementing PHP 7.4?

Tags: drupal, php

Having just upgraded a site to 5.47.2 and noting that PHP 7.4 is recommended I rashly took this seriously :) and ended up with 3 messages that splat themselves over the top of the majority of screensm making it unusable.  Here's one:
*"Deprecated: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated in /home/dcmadmin/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.flexmailer/flexmailer.civix.php on line 246"*
So I'm back with PHP 7.3 as I couldn't find a way to suppress them. So can these messages be supressed? This is a Drupal 7 install with error logging set to 'None' which obviously doesn't include these.

Answer (score 2):

For the flexmailer one, note that flexmailer is now a core extension so you shouldn't have that copy in sites/default/files since it's outdated.

For other warnings, it's pretty much just extensions that have that curly braces warning now. Any extension that hasn't updated its `*.civix.php` files yet.

Comment: Thanks, so the flexmailer extension can be uninstalled?

Comment: In theory that's all that's needed and then when the files are deleted and the extension reinstalled civi should find the core one, but I can't guarantee that's what happens in every install. I would temporarily move it somewhere instead of deleting in case the site completely borks and you need to put it back.

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful.  I had the old Flexmailer 1.1.1 and now I've got the latest version.

Comment: What do we do with extensions like Flexmailer that are now a part of core? I saw another thread that said to disable, uninstall, and reinstall. I did that for 7 extensions but I am still getting the messages. If it is a part of core, can we just disable and uninstall it? If so, what other extension are now included with core?

Comment: Which messages are you getting. The original topic here was about the `Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated`. There's plenty of other deprecation messages that might still be around that need separate type of handling.

Comment: Same messages and same issue after updating to PHP 7.4   https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2359